# Relationship issue in Laravel

Tags: model, relational-database, laravel-5.5

I have 3 tables `applicants`,`skills` and `applicant_skill`. Here `applicant_skill` is the pivot table. `applicant_skill` table has 2 columns `applicant_id`, `skill_id`. One `Applicant` has many `Skills`. One `Skill` has many `Applicants`.

I wrote below function in model `Applicants.php`

```
public function applicantSkill()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ApplicantSkill::class);
    }
```

I wrote below function in model `Skills.php`

```
public function applicantSkill()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Applicant_skill::class);
}
```

I wrote below function in model `ApplicantSkill.php`

```
public function Applicants()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Applicants::class);
}
```

I am trying to fetch `applicants` in `ApplicantController.php` like below

```
$applicants = Applicants::with('applicant_skill', 'applicant_skill.skills')->paginate();
```

I am getting below error.

[image]

Comment: relationship which u had created in Applicants model is public function applicantSkill(), then you have to use as Applicants::with('applicantSkill')

Comment: Thanks @MayankMajithya. But I have to fetch records with `applicant_skill` data.

Comment: i had update my comment

Comment: Where is the mistake of mine ? Thanks.

Comment: you have to use relationship as defined in model .

Comment: yes that's it..

Answer (score 1):

You have to use relationship as you have defined in models.

Model :- Applicants.php

```
public function Applicants()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Applicants::class);
}
```

you can use relationship in controller like,

```
$applicants = Applicants::with('Applicants')->paginate();
```

You can refer doc here, [Laravel-Eloquent-Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships).